# Is there a tangible benefit of synchronising the sample clock to the laser pulses in a resonant scanning two-photon microscope?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging

NI data acquisition cards offer a possibility of synchronising data acquisition with the pulses of a 80 MHz Ti:Sapphire laser. This supposedly helps improve the signal to noise ratio, since the true fluorescence signals should be time-locked to the laser pulses, while electrical noise in the PMT amplifier circuits and noise from the PMT itself are not.

Has anyone done a head-to-head comparison of SNR on a two-photon microscope with and without triggered acquisition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a highly technical question without any cognitive sciences aspect to it. Since it is an interesting and well-researched question I would recommend migration to Biology.SE or comparable site. It might get better answers there as I am pretty certain it will receive no answers here.

Comment: SE just shut down a proposal for a site dedicated to questions such as this (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99716/neuroscience) suggesting that it would drain audience and resources from the CogSci site. I think as most of the followers of the proposal would've argued, and your comment confirms, this isn't the case.

Comment: Curently Bio and CogSci are the sites for Neuroscience and this topic is shared between the two sites. Bio would survive happily with Neuro excluded, but CogSci has a hard time as it is. The number of basic neuroscientists active on the two sites are not more than a small handful. I doubt a dedicated site would survive. One way or another, your chances on getting an answer on your question are better at Bio than here.

Comment: As [discussed on meta](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/2136/21), questions like this are since considered to be welcome here, and I thus reopened this question. This is a change in how such questions generally were treated in the past, hence the mixed signals. My apologies.

Comment: @StevenJeuris,  I have never said it is offtopic here and +1d. Just trying to get this great question get the attention it deserves.  Dupes are discouraged across sites, hence explaining my vote.

Comment: Great question!